# React Functional Components, how to export more than one component per file

Tags: reactjs

I need to export different components for the same page because they act just as configurations to render other components, I´m new to react so I struggling in finding the solution for this. Here is a codesandbox with a simple example of what I want to achieve: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-elion-fq4zt?file=/src/App.js

Thanks!

---- EDITED ----

Thanks for all the answers, thanks to that I realized I had a typo in the component naming, that's why my previous tries didn't work.

I leave here the updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-elion-fq4zt?file=/src/App.js), since it might be useful for others:

Comment: ```import {ComponentOne,ComponentTwo} from "./PageOne";```

Comment: Also this is about ES6 not React.

Answer (score 5):

To export more than one component in a module simply do the following:

```
export const ComponentOne = () => <span>Some content for ComponentOne</span>;

export const ComponentTwo = () => <span>Some content for ComponentOne</span>;
```

Then, when you need to import these components simply do:

```
import { ComponentOne, ComponentTwo } from "./path/of/components"
```

Please note that the import is with `{}` because the components are not exported as default.

On the other side, if you have only a component in your file you can simply do the following:

```
const Component = () => <span>Some content for Component</span>;

export default Component;
```

And than import as default, without the `{}` as in the following example:

```
import Component from "./path/of/components"
```

Answer (score 3):

// component.js

```
export const someCom1 = () => {
   return <div>Hello 1</div>
}

export const someCom2 = () => {
   return <div>Hello 2</div>
}
```

// parent.js

```
import {someCom1, someCom2 } from './component.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

in your page file remove "export" from the: export function componentOn

and keep at the button: export { ComponentOne, ComponentTwo };

to import it use: import {ComponentOne,ComponentTwo} from "./PageOne";

Answer (score 0):

You can keep both components in a single wrapper like this

**PageOne.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ComponentOne from "./ComponentOne";
import ComponentTwo from "./ComponentTwo";

export default function PageOne() {
  return (
    <>
      <ComponentOne title={"This is the title"} />;
      <ComponentTwo description={"This is the description"} />;
    </>
  );
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import PageOne from "./PageOne";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PageOne />
    </div>
  );
}
```